# Javascript Regex Negative Look-ahead (Validating EXACTLY {X} Occurrences and Not More)

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, regex-lookarounds

I think it's called a negative look-ahead `/x(?!y)/`, but I'm not sure since I just started doing regex stuff today. I'm trying to validate the following:

```
  // Matches aa-00 through ZZ-99
  var regex = /([a-zA-Z]{2}(?!\b))((-){1})([0-9]{2}(?!\B))/;

  var result = regex.test("EV-05"); // Should pass
  Console.log("EV-05: " + result + "\n");

  result = regex.test("ev-09"); // Should pass
  Console.log("ev-09: " + result + "\n");

  result = regex.test("eV-11"); // Should pass
  Console.log("eV-11: " + result + "\n");

  result = regex.test("Ev-30"); // Should pass
  Console.log("Ev-30: " + result + "\n");

  result = regex.test("ev03"); // Should fail
  Console.log("ev03: " + result + "\n");

  result = regex.test("e-17"); // Should fail
  Console.log("e-17: " + result + "\n");

  result = regex.test("ev-5"); // Should fail
  Console.log("ev-5: " + result + "\n");

  result = regex.test("evv-36"); // Should fail
  Console.log("evv-36: " + result + "\n");

  result = regex.test("ev-019"); // Should fail
  Console.log("ev-019: " + result + "\n");

  result = regex.test("ev--05"); // Should fail
  Console.log("ev--05: " + result + "\n");
```

Here's what I want:

`LETTER#LETTER#HYPHEN#DIGIT#DIGIT` (honestly have no idea how to describe that in a readable fashion).

I do not want to allow input of extra values for any of those 5 parameters. It must be exactly 2 letters followed by a hyphen, followed by 2 digits (0-9). I want to validate that there are not 3+ letters, nor 3+ digits.

I thought that the {n} occurrence marker for each would be enough, but it still returns `true` when there are 3+ letters/digits (as is the intention of the {n} marker). Thus I tried the negative look-ahead to return false if another word `\b` was found for the letters, and non-word `\B` for the digits. But that didn't work either.

If I remove the negative look-aheads and the `\b` & `\B` and just stick with **the original**:

```
var regex = /[a-zA-Z]{2}(-){1}[0-9]{2}/;
```

Then half of the values are valid, but the ones with *extra* characters/digits are also considered valid.

**Long story short**: How do I ensure that there are *exactly* `X` amount of occurrences something, and return false when there are extra? Maybe I'm just messing up the NLA implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making things a little more complicated than they should be here. You can use something like this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}$/;
```

`^` will match the beginning of the string and `$` will match the end of the string.

This regex will allow only strings containing 2 letters, followed by one hyphen and followed by 2 digits. You can rewrite `[0-9]` as `\d` as well in javascript.

---

```
/([a-zA-Z]{2}(?!\b))((-){1})([0-9]{2}(?!\B))/;
```

This doesn't quite work as you might expect. `(?!\b)` prevents a word boundary from occurring immediately after the 2 letters, which will make your valid strings fail.

`((-){1})` You don't need so many parenthesis, even if you want to group those, because there's hardly anything to group. Use parentheses to capture stuff you'll use later on. The `{1}` is redundant as well. I have never seen a single concrete use of `{1}`. `{n}` is useful when `n` is greater than 1.

`([0-9]{2}(?!\B))` Again, the parentheses are not quite useful, but here, you used a negated word boundary, which should work well (similar to `$` but anywhere in the string).

If you want to match such format anywhere in a string, then you can use word boundaries as follows:

```
/\b[a-zA-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}\b/;
```

Comment: @plalx neat, I'd never seen `[A-z]` before and had always used the `i` flag.

Comment: Perfect! Sorry for such a ridiculous question, this is my first attempt at regexing and I only got as far as I did by reading the docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). I didn't really understand what `^` and `$` meant until now. Works perfectly though, thank you :)

Comment: @plalx This will allow more characters than [A-Za-z] because it will also match the characters: [ \ ] ^ _ ` (6 additional characters)

Comment: @Mathletics Be very careful with that range! See my above comment.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice It's okay, you came out the your question better than a few minutes back :)

Comment: @Jerry: If by "be very careful" with `[A-z]` you mean "never use it", I agree. ;)

Comment: @AlanMoore Well, yea, unless you do want to get that whole range in your regex for some obscure reason...

Comment: Not even then.  All you would be doing is showing off your own cleverness at the expense of making the regex harder to read.

Comment: @AlanMoore That's an obscure reason enough I think ;)